# cannot connect react to socket io server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I wrote a simple hook to connect react and socket.io:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { v1 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:3001'

export const useSocketConnection = () => {
  const { gameId } = useParams()
  const userId = uuid()

  const socketRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('connectSocket')
    socketRef.current = io(SERVER_URL, {
      query: { gameId }
    })
    socketRef.current.emit('join-room', {
      userId
    })

    return () => {
      console.log('disconnectSocket')
      socketRef.current.disconnect()
    }
  }, [gameId])
}
```

the server code is pretty simple:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socket = require("socket.io");
const io = socket(server);
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('This endpoint works pretty fine')
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('connected user', socket.id, new Date()) //this log works

  socket.on('join-room', () => {
    console.log('hope this will work') //doesn't work at all
  })
});

server.listen(3001, () => console.log('server is running on port 3001'));
```

when component renders `useEffect` hook hires just one time(look screen below)

[image]

But server gets one more connection every 5 or 6 seconds I don't know why. If look to the image below each connection has new id and the period of adding new connections is 6 seconds. Also `socket.on('join room')` doesnt work at all :(

[image]

Please help to figure out what Im doing wrong, couldn't find nothing helpful in the internet .Thank you in advance <3

Comment: I've figured out that problem is on the client-side, and after downgrading `socket.io-client` version, the problem has gone by itself, I did everything as shown in socket io documentation, so I don't know what to say, guess the issue is in the new version of library and will be fixed in the nearest future

Comment: But maybe I've missed something on the initialization stage, so I left the question still open for the others who can face with this issue